# Attribute option_id instead of value

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, debugging

In the `mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` file that I override in my custom theme I have the following code:

```
$attributeCode = 'myattributecode';
if($value = $this->getProduct()->getData($attributeCode));):
echo $value;
```

(Sorry, the div elements are not supported by this site.)

On the product page I get the  option_id instead of value.

When I am doing the following, trying to debug:

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('tempspreparation'); var_dump($attribute);die();
```

I am getting the huge array with:

> ["myattributecode"]=> *RECURSION*

for my attribute code.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Any help will be largely appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Firstly recommend you to use xDebug. What do you want to find inside attribute object?

Comment: The attribute value. Right now I am getting the attribute option_id.

Thanks zhartaunik!

Comment: $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); then foreach, then get any value from _data array

Comment: Do you mean this? $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

Comment: Yep, smth like this. Does it work for you?

Comment: Zhartaunik, your thing has worked! Make an answer and I will accept it as answered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26434/discussion-between-supersonic-and-zhartaunik).

Comment: Thank you. Anyway I'd recommend you to install xDebug. I cannot even imagine how to work without it in magento.

Comment: it is still not good. I am getting array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["value"]=> string(2) "16" ["label"]=> string(2) "24" } [1]=> array(2) { ["value"]=> string(2) "15" ["label"]=> string(2) "43" } [2]=> array(2) { ["value"]=> string(2) "14" ["label"]=> string(2) "48" } } . The values of the ["label"] should be in the ["value"], because in the eav_attribute_option_value table of my database they are in the "value" column.

Comment: updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try get attribute options like this:

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

foreach ($options as $option) {
     $optionId = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($option['value']);
}
```

Probably exists more clear solution, but it's fast and workable :)

Comment: I am still getting the value of the wrong database column. I don't understand why Magento looks in the option_id column and not in the value column. I'll try to create another attribute set and all the custom attributes from zero and let you know about the result.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm getting proper IDs

Comment: Can it be because I have deleted an attribute set and created a new one? I think it must be an sql query problem. I can not think of anything more stupid than change the values manually in the wrong database column fields so that they match those in the right one.

Comment: If you did it via magento, I think it should not be a problem. If you did via DB - I think everything can happen)

Comment: I only did it through Magento

Comment: What returns $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId('option_value'); with any option value?

Comment: it returns: string(2) "19", i.e. the option_id.

Comment: @Supersonic in case you're wondering (I know it's been a long time since you asked this question) this is a bug: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/173054/2380

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106164/is-there-a-simpler-way-to-get-an-attributes-frontend-value

getAttributeText() is used for:
- dropdowns
- multiselects
- only with products (not a general EAV trick)

E.G.: 
$value = $product->getAttributeText($attribute_code);

Comment: Cool! Good to know! Thanks!

Is there some theory or documentation on EAV?