# getOptionId method returns invalid option ID

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, magento-1

Magento 1.9.0.1

Class: `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract`

Method:

```
public function getOptionId($value)
{
    foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
        if (strcasecmp($option['label'], $value)==0 || $option['value'] == $value) {
            return $option['value'];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method is usually used for obtaining option's ID by option's label:

```
$attribute = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code);
// validate attribute
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    // load option id by value text
    return $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($attribute_option);
} else {
    return false;
}
```

This method works well for text labels. But in my case option's labels are numbers. E.g:

1. Option's label is 14.
2. `getAllOptions` returns array of options:

   ```
   array(
   array(
       'label' => 1,
       'value' => 14
   ),
   array(
       'label' => 14,
       'value' => 2
   )
   )
   ```
3. I expect that `getOptionId` method will return the second element of  the array. But it return the first due to this comparison `$option['value'] == $value`.

So what is the purpose for the `$option['value'] == $value` comparison? It turns out that we are comparing a label with option's ID. Is it a bug? or does it have some purpose?

Answer (score 2):

This is a <strike>bug</strike> stupid implementation I just faced too on 1.9.3.2.

**The problem can be replicated if an attribute option has the same id as an other attribute option label**

The `getOptionId` method is kind of weird, because as you can see from the code, **the condition is true if the parameter matches the label OR matches the value**

The workaround is used in my case where I only wanted to get a label match was to write a method like this:

```
public function getOptionIdByLabel($source, $label)
{
    foreach ($source->getAllOptions() as $option) {
        if (strcasecmp($option['label'], $label)==0) {
           return $option['value'];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then in my code I did :

```
$source = $attribute->getSource();
$optionValue = $this->getOptionIdByLabel($source, $label);
```

Comment: perfect, thanks !